# Cache user remote credentials for command line tool

Tags: python, caching, credentials

I'm designing a Python command line tool that will essentially be a wrapper for a few REST APIs. The general idea is so that the user can make remote changes without having to leave the terminal.

The only detail I'm not really sure about is how to cache the user credentials so that they don't have to enter `username` and `password` every time they make a remote call. I'm worried about leaving user credentials exposed for long periods of time when they're not using the tool. Is there a typical way to do this without writing a file and making a thread that destroys the file after a certain time has passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the `keyring` package from pypi, then you can wrap it up with some utility functions:

```
SERVICE_NAME = 'confluence_api'


def get_login_cli(username = None, prompt = False):
    '''
    Get the password for the username out of the keyring.  If the password
    isn't found in the keyring, ask for it from the command line.
    '''

    disp_username = False

    if username is None or prompt:
        username = getpass.getuser()
        disp_username = True

    passwd = keyring.get_password(SERVICE_NAME, username)

    if passwd is None or prompt:

        if disp_username:
            print 'login: %s' % username

        passwd = getpass.getpass()
        set_password(username, passwd)

    return (username, passwd)


def set_password(username, passwd):
    '''
    Writes the password to the keyring.
    '''

    keyring.set_password(SERVICE_NAME, username, passwd)
```

And then your run-time script can call it like so:

```
username, passwd = get_login_cli(username, **kwargs)

print("username = %s" % (username))
```

So after logging in, the password is cached and you won't be prompted the second time.  `keyring` uses the native platform's keyring to store the credentials, and I believe after `N` time has passed, you will be prompted again, but you'll have to read the docs on `keyring` to know what `N` is.